# How can i refresh data or how to after sending email how can i display on other activity

Tags: android, mysql, xampp

I am trying to create email section in my application using xampp and mysql. If user sends email then it will be shown to support team. I have created bd ID auto generated, KEY unique fro each email, user email, subject, user message, support message, created at, updated.

Comment: What work have you done on Android?

Comment: I just done login and registration profile all basic things now i want to create email section in app

Comment: What coding you have done for email?